# Determining the PMF of the maximum of dependent RVs

Tags: probability, self-study

Five numbers are selected without replacement from 1 to 10. The PMF of the $M$, the maximum of the 5 is desired. My approach is as follows:

If I let $X_1,X_2, X_3,X_4,X_5$ be the variables representing the 5 numbers,

$P(X_1\leq M)=\frac{M}{10}$

$P(X_2\leq M)=\frac{M-1}{9}$

$P(X_3\leq M)=\frac{M-2}{8}$

$P(X_4\leq M)=\frac{M-3}{7}$

$P(X_5\leq M)=\frac{M-4}{6}$

I have a question here. I know that the $X_i's$ are not independent but by choosing to express them the way I did, does the following expression work?

$P(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5\leq M)=P(M\leq m)=\frac{m}{10}\frac{m-1}{9}\frac{m-2}{8}\frac{m-3}{7}\frac{m-4}{6}$ for $m$ from $5$ to $10$, and $0$ otherwise. From here, I can just find the PMF using the above described CDF.

It seems to make sense but I can't explain why it works given that the $X_i$'s are not independent.

Comment: Consider that you were actually conditioning on the lower index observations, If you modify your expressions to take account of the conditioning you were using, it might look like it makes sense. That is, consider that you can write P(ABC...) = P(A)P(B|A)P(C|A,B)... etc and then notice what you actually did there.

Comment: I find it easier to compute the CDF directly from the equivalent characterization of this sampling as being uniform over all five-element subsets. That implies $\Pr(M\le m)$ is the proportion of five-element subsets of the integers from $1$ through $10$ that are, at the same time, five-element subsets of the integers from $1$ through $m$.  It's immediate that $$\Pr(M\le m) = \frac{\binom{m}{5}}{\binom{10}{5}}.$$